# encrypted keystore /trustedstore password for Kafka broker

Tags: encryption, apache-kafka, keystore

In my current project I am using SSL connection for Kafka and below are my current setup for server properties files :

```
broker.id=1
listeners= SSL://123.456.789.110:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/keys/keystore
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/CApath/trustedstore
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

But I don' want to use cleartest keystore and trustedstore password in server properties file .

I am using Kafka version 2.0.0 .

Answer (score 4):

From Kafka 2.0 onwards, it's possible to store all passwords encrypted in Zookeeper instead of plain text in the properties file.

See the [dynamic broker configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#dynamicbrokerconfigs) section in the Kafka documentation. The "Updating Password Configs in ZooKeeper Before Starting Brokers" subsection has details how to set this up.

See also [KIP-226](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-226+-+Dynamic+Broker+Configuration#KIP-226-DynamicBrokerConfiguration-SecuringpasswordsinZooKeeper) which contains all the technical details